# how to use a python3 custom function within a template file of flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

in flask, the html files are stored inside the `/templates` directory. I'm still new to this microframework and python3. 
in my main python code, I have a function like e.g

```
""" this is the function that I need to use wihtin the html template below"""
def get_status(statusNum):
      if statusNum == 1:
           return 'active'
      if statusNum == 0:
           return 'inactive'


"""this is the function that renders the html"""
@app.route('/')
def index():
    render_template('index.html')
```

then inside the index.html , I have this simple code e.g

```
<html>
<head><title>My Page</title></head>
<body>
<ul>
{% for listing in listings %}
    <li>{{listing.status_num}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This `listing.status_num` value is either 1 or 0 , in order for me to display a text such as 'active' or 'inactive', I want to use my python function like this get_status(listing.status_num) within the html template.... is that even possible ? how to properly use a python function inside a flask html template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are multiple approaches to this problem.

The first and simplest for your use case is to just check for that in the template itself using the provided Jinja2 options.

```html
<html>
<head><title>My Page</title></head>
<body>
<ul>
{% for listing in listings %}
    <li>
        {% if listing.status_num == 1 %}
            active
        {% elif listing.status_num == 0 %}
            inactive
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Another option is to add a context processor to your app. Context processors inject new variables automatically into the context of a template and run before the template is rendered.

```py
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def get_status(statusNum):
        if statusNum == 1:
            return 'active'
        if statusNum == 0:
            return 'inactive'
    return dict(get_status=get_status)
```

And then you can use it in your template like this:

```html
<html>
<head><title>My Page</title></head>
<body>
<ul>
{% for listing in listings %}
    <li>
        {{ get_status(listing.status_num) }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for this. I used the 2nd approach of creating a context_processor ....the first option looks weird and redundant and I might encounter problem in future

Comment: This method is incredibly useful if you use app.config to store a PREFIX that should be the top directory of the virtual path to the application. While the reverse proxy tricks with [appdispatch](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/appdispatch/) help with the url_for() calls, you can just add a prefix() function to the @app.context_processor for any hard-coded links.